# Timer not working intent error

Tags: android, android-intent, timer, countdowntimer

I'm making a timer that switches form one activity to another in 3 seconds. Here is the code:

```
    new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.single_image);
        TextView mTextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);            
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            img.setImageResource(resource);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
        Intent intent = Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Image", resource);
        intent.putExtra("difficulty", difficulty);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
         }
      }.start();
}
```

It gets an error at

```
Initent intent = Intent(this,GameActivity.class);
```

Its states the following:

```
The method Intent(new CountDownTimer(){}, Class<GameActivity>) is undefined for 
the type new CountDownTimer(){}
```

any idea why i get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `this` refers to your `CountDownTimer` class. You need to use your `Activity Context`. Change

```
Intent intent = Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = Intent(ActivityName.this, GameActivity.class);
```

Comment: Is this class inside of an `Activity`? Also, make sure you are saving and rerunning the project.

Comment: now it says:

Multiple markers at this line
 - The method Intent(new CountDownTimer(){}, Class<GameActivity>) is undefined for the type new 
  CountDownTimer(){}

Comment: If you made that change and you're still getting the same error then it sounds like you aren't saving the change. Make sure you are running with the new change.

Comment: I can show you the code in a chat if you want to?

Tx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66292/discussion-between-kees-til-and-codemagic).

Answer (score 1):

The Error is that this in that line refers to your instance of `CountDownTimer`. You have to give the reference to the Activity itself. In the case that the `CountDownTimer` is located anywhere in your Activity class simply change it to `Intent intent = Intent(YourActivity.this, GameActivity.class);`.